# A question about Hamiltonian phase flow

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, mathematics

> Show that if a one-parameter group of difeomorphisms of a symplectic manifold preserves the symplectic structure then it is a locally hamiltonian phase flow.

Note that

> A locally hamiltonian vector field on a symplectic manifold $(M^{2n}, \omega^2)$ is the vector field $I \omega^1$, where $\omega^1$ is a closed 1-form on $M^{2n}$ and $\omega^1(\eta) = \omega^2(\eta, I\omega^1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. Prove that a one-parameter group $(\Phi_t)_{t\in I}$ of diffeomorphisms $\Phi_t: M \to M$ is generated by a vector field $X\in\Gamma(M)$.
2. Prove that if the one-parameter group $(\Phi_t)_{t\in I}$ preserves the a form $\omega$ then ${\cal L}_{X}\omega =0$.
3. Prove that ${\cal L}_{X}\omega =0$ together with the fact that $\omega$ is a symplectic two-form (in particular the fact that $\omega$ is non-degenerate) imply that $X$ is locally a [Hamiltonian vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_vector_field).

Comment: Could you explain it further? Many thanks!